# Convolution and its inverse Fourier transform

Tags: visualization, fourier-analysis

I have two functions `f[x,y]` and `g[x,y]` calculated on a grid `{x,y}`. Then I perform numerical Fourier transforms,

```
FTf=Fourier[dataf]; 
FTg=Fourier[datag]
```

I am looking for convolution $w=f*g$. To calculate it, I do

```
listw=InverseFourier[FTf*FTg]
```

and finally I would like to plot density of $w$. To do it, I reshape `listw` and then construct list `data={{x1,y1,w1},...}`
and finally

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

Everything seems ok but the final plot is quite strange. Is everything ok with my derivation?

To be specific, the following code presents the simpler version:

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
g[x_, y_] := Exp[-4*(x^2 + y^2)];
fdata = Table[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}];
gdata = Table[g[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}];
FTf = Fourier[fdata];
FTg = Fourier[gdata];
listw = InverseFourier[FTf*FTg];
wvalues = Abs[ArrayReshape[listw, 21^2]];
xypairs = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1];
data = ArrayReshape[Transpose[{xypairs, wvalues}], {21^2, 3}];
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

which produces plot:

[image]

For simple functions, I can calculate FT explicitly:

```
FTf1 = FourierTransform[f[x, y], {x, y}, {w1, w2}];
FTf2 = FourierTransform[g[x, y], {x, y}, {w1, w2}];
wfunction = InverseFourierTransform[FTf1*FTf2, {w1, w2}, {x, y}]
```

and then can density plot `wfunction[x_,y_]`:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the data as well? Also, why is the plot "strange"? That is, what had you expected and how is the output different from that?

Comment: @MarcoB the data is huge arrays, I try to realize the simpler example.

Comment: @MarcoB I have tried to provide the simple example of my code. I assume that the problem comes from manipulations with xy-grid and array reshaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `Fourier` puts the zero frequency Fourier component at the beginning of the output list.

```
center[array_] := 
RotateRight[Map[RotateRight[#, Floor[Length[array]/2]] &, array], 
Floor[Length[array]/2]]

f[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
g[x_, y_] := Exp[-4*(x^2 + y^2)];
fdata = Table[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}];
gdata = Table[g[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}];
FTf = center[Fourier[fdata]];
FTg = center[Fourier[gdata]];
listw = center[InverseFourier[FTf*FTg]];
wvalues = Abs[ArrayReshape[listw, 21^2]];
xypairs = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1];
data = ArrayReshape[Transpose[{xypairs, wvalues}], {21^2, 3}];
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask one more question: it seems that numerical Fourier is quite inaccurate (cf. numerical and explicit plots)... What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Discrete sampling is equivalent to bandwidth limiting your Fourier transform (see Nyquist's sampling theorem etc); in other words when you discretely sample your functions you are in effect truncating your Fourier transforms above a certain cutoff frequency, and that's causing the reconstruction via the inverse Fourier to be inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

Let's compare convolution in the time domain and the spatial domain. Consider the convolution of two signals h and x.

```
h = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3};  
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1};  
n = Length[x] + Length[h] - 1;
xPad = PadRight[x, n];
```

The convolution is:

```
yConv = ListConvolve[h, xPad, {1, 1}]

{1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, -6, 6, -18, 6, -30, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3}
```

Using the FFTs of h and x:

```
ffth = Fourier[PadRight[h, n], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
fftx =  Fourier[PadRight[x, n], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
yFourier = InverseFourier[ffth fftx, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

(same as above)

The padding is used in the Fourier because both signals must have the same length. The padding in the time domain is needed because you want to implement circular convolution in order to be the same as the Fourier method.

Comment: To be honest, I do understand Yours answer clearly. In my example both arrays `fdata` and `gdata` have the same length. Could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: If your two data sequences already have the same length then you can ignore/remove the padding.