# Numerical evaluation of convolution: one more question

Tags: fourier-analysis

Recently I have asked [the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224235/convolution-and-its-inverse-fourier-transform) about convolution and how to calculate it numerically.

I still misunderstand the following moment: if I have two functions defined on a grid `{x,y}`, so I have two arrays `f[x,y]` and `g[x,y]`. Then, I use `Fourier` to obtain Fourier transforms of my functions, `FTf` and `FTg`, respectively, and compute

```
listw=InverseFourier[FTf*FTg]
```

The question is following: if initial functions were defined in domain `{x,y}` can I assume that values of convolution $w=f*g$ are defined on the same domain? Can I just use `ListPlot3D` with input `{x,y,w[x,y]}` where `x` and `y` correspond to original grid?

Consider the example with `f[x,y]=g[x,y]=Exp[-(x^2+y^2)]` evaluated for `x` and `y` from `[0,1]` with step `0.1`.

Numerical evaluation is:

```
center[array_] := 
 RotateRight[Map[RotateRight[#, Floor[Length[array]/2]] &, array], 
  Floor[Length[array]/2]];
s=0.1;
a = 1.;
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
g[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
n = Table[x, {x, -a, a, s}] // Length;
fdata = Table[f[x, y], {x, -a, a, s}, {y, -a, a, s}];
gdata = Table[g[x, y], {x, -a, a, s}, {y, -a, a, s}];
FTf = center[Fourier[fdata]];
FTg = center[Fourier[gdata]];
listw = Abs[1/Total@Flatten[gdata, 1]*Sqrt[n]*center[InverseFourier[FTf*FTg]]];
```

List density plot of `listw` with mentioned `{x,y}` values gives

[image]

Then, "exact" calculation,

```
FTf1 = FourierTransform[f[x, y], {x, y}, {w1, w2}];
FTf2 = FourierTransform[g[x, y], {x, y}, {w1, w2}];
wfunction = 2*Pi*InverseFourierTransform[FTf1*FTf2, {w1, w2}, {x, y}]
```

gives the following density plot,

[image]

I do not understand how it happens. I try to take into account scaling factors using [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206788/discrete-fourier-transform-and-convolution-scaling-factor/206811#206811)

Comment: It will give you a grid from which you can extract values and integer coordinates {x,y} into a flat list using `flat = Flatten[MapIndexed[Append[#2,#1]&, listw,{2}],1]`. If you need to rescale the integer coordinates back into some other domain, use `Map[{Rescale[#[[1]], {xmin,xmax}],Rescale[#[[2]], {ymin,ymax}],#[[3]]}&, flat]`

Comment: Thank you! But does it work for domain, for instance, {xmin,xmax}={-1,1}? Seems not

Comment: @flinty I would like to emphasize that I understand how to obtain flat list from `listw` but I am not sure that this function is defined on the the same lattice

Comment: Fourier and InverseFourier don't know about the "lattice" - they just process 2d arrays. Please expain what's wrong with using `Rescale` to `{xmin,xmax}={-1,1}` after the invert. Is your grid regular?

Comment: In order to find out just make an experiment with 1 function. Make direct and inverse transform,  plot as you suggest, and see what happens. From this, you will get an idea on what happens with two functions. See also `ListCorrelate`.

Comment: @yarchik I add the example with simple functions and provide plots

Comment: There are some mistakes when I execute your code: Delta is not defined, is it ok to have s=1?

Comment: @yarchik yes, I have checked my code.